# How can I play .SWF in a Java Application?

Tags: java, flash

Could anyone tell me how to play a SWF file inside a Java application *or* does anyone know of a free plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look at JFlashPlayer. http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer/

I have only played around with it a little, but it does have a developer license fee.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [JSwiff](http://www.jswiff.com/) . I never used it myself but it seems quite useful plus it is open source ;)