# How can I play Adobe Flash .SWF files in a Java Desktop Application?

Tags: java, flash, netbeans, desktop-application

I've done some searching around but there doesn't seem to be much from this decade that answers my question. I do my development in NetBeans. I found/was directed to a link to the DJProject, but integrating it into NetBeans seems to be quite complicated and I can't find a step-by-step for idiots that is less than a year old. I was hoping for something along the lines of a simple library JAR file I could just import into the application but so far I have found nothing like that. All of my google searching has revealed that either I am not looking for the right things or not looking in the right way, so I was hoping for some direction to something that will work.

I notice in the "Similar Questions" panel to the right there is one worded nearly identical [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917982/how-can-i-play-swf-in-a-java-application), but it's over 5 years old and the answer link is discontinued, and the other answer link seems to connect to some Asian hair loss treatment website?

Several answers I've seen recommend bringing in the JavaFX Web Browser, but I was hoping for something a little more light-weight, similar to the C# solution for playing Flash files.

I saw the Transform SFW java library but I think that's more for creating SWF files in Java, and not really what I need. And the JFlashPlayer doesn't seem to be available anymore.

Lastly, I hate asking a "Where can I find it/What should I use to..." question here on SO since those kinds of questions draw all sorts of flack, so this is kind of a last resort for me. If there is a better place for me to post this question that will get me an answer faster, please direct me there so that I can go pester someone else.

Comment: have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275174/embed-swf-file-to-my-jframe

Comment: Ah! Yes I did but I misplaced it. Thank you I will try this one out and see how it works.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov
Taking a closer look at this I see somethings that I think will inhibit my process: Namely the line where it's looking specifically for a windows file. The applications I will be developing should be as close to cross-platform friendly as possible. Also, this answer seems to be on the right track, but also a bit old. I was hoping for something a bit more up to date (within the past 1, maybe 2 years).